# Show $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{4}+x}} = \frac{2 \Gamma(1/3) \Gamma(7/6)}{\sqrtπ}≈2.80436$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, pi

> How the following integral can be calculated?
>   $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{4}+x}}$$

I tried to substitute $\sqrt{x^{3}+1}=u$, but that would not help.

Another way I used was $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{4}+x}}\le\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{2}}$$

which again is not useful, since I'm looking for a convergent integral.
Also [integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) could not solve the integral and WolframAlpha gave the following solution:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{4}+x}} = \frac{2 \Gamma(1/3) \Gamma(7/6)}{\sqrtπ}≈2.80436$$

I don't know where this comes from, so can someone solve this integral or at least show me that the integral is convergent?

Comment: Hint: Substitute $\frac{1}{x^3+1}=t$ then use the beta function.

Comment: @thank you so much, but I still don't know about beta function, do you know a way to show that the integral is convergent?

Comment: @user715522 Do you want to evaluate the integral or do you want to show that it converges?

Comment: well I prefer the first one, but it seems to be a little complicated, so I just want to show that the integral is convergent

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to find that result. Well, you can split the integral as $\int_0^1 +\int_1^\infty$. For the second part, use what already you stated in the question, $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{4}+x}}\le\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{2}}$. Can you deal with the first part too?

Comment: @Zacky, thank you, but for the first one I get a non convergent integral

Comment: I'm not sure how you possibly showed that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4+x}}dx$ doesn't converge. You can substitute $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and then you get $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^3+1}}dt$, and show that this converges.

Comment: @Zacky,thank you so much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{x^4+x}}\stackrel{x\mapsto\frac1x}=-\int_\infty^0\frac1{x^2}\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{\frac1x+\frac1{x^4}}}=\int_0^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$$
From here it is even clearer why to apply the substitution hinted by *Zacky* in the comments. I will follow a different track. Recall [Ramanujan's Master Theorem (RMT)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujansMasterTheorem.html) and reshape the integral accordingly to obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}&=\int_0^\infty(1+x^3)^{-1/2}{\rm d}x&&;x^3\mapsto x\\
&=\frac13\int_0^\infty x^{1/3-1}(1+x)^{-1/2}{\rm d}x\\
&=\frac13\int_0^\infty x^{1/3-1}\left[\sum_{n\geq0}\binom{2n}n\frac{(-x)^n}{4^n}\right]{\rm d}x\\
&=\frac13\int_0^\infty x^{1/3-1}\left[\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\phi(n)}{n!}(-x)^n\right]&&;\phi(n)=\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{4^n\Gamma(n+1)}\\
&=\frac13\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\phi\left(-\frac13\right)&&;\text{RMT}\\
&=\frac13\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac23+1\right)}{4^{-1/3}\Gamma\left(-\frac13+1\right)}\\
&=\frac{2^{2/3}}3\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac13\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}
\end{align*}
[This expression evaluates to $2.803~642\dots$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%5E%281%2F3%29%2F3*Gamma%5E2%281%2F3%29%2FGamma%282%2F3%29), matching WolframAlpha's overall result numerically. We can do better by using [Legendre's Duplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html) for $z=1/6$ to see
\begin{align*}
\Gamma\left(2\frac16\right)&=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}2^{2(1/6)-1}\Gamma\left(\frac16\right)\Gamma\left(\frac16+\frac12\right)\\
\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)&=\frac{2^{-2/3}}{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac16\right)\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)\\
\therefore~\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)&=\sqrt\pi2^{2/3}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\Gamma\left(\frac16\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}
Using this result we further obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{2^{2/3}}3\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac13\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}&=\frac{2^{2/3}}3\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac13\right)}{\sqrt\pi2^{2/3}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\Gamma\left(\frac16\right)^{-1}}\\
&=\frac1{3\sqrt\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\Gamma\left(\frac16\right)\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\Gamma\left(\frac76\right)
\end{align*}

> $$\therefore~\int_0^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{x^4+x}}~=~\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\Gamma\left(\frac76\right)$$

I do not think there is an completely elementary way to obtain this result (arguably, using the Beta Function is more elementary than RMT) as the final expression is in terms of the Gamma Function.

---

Regarding convergence. Split the integral as
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{x^4+x}}=\int_0^1\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{x^4+x}}+\int_1^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{x^4+x}}$$
Now, we have $x^4+x\geq x^4$ and for $x\in[1;\infty)$ this shows that the latter integral converges. Regarding the first one, apply $x\mapsto\frac1x$ and then using that $x^3+1\geq x^3$ shows that the first integral converges aswell. Continue as above to obtain its value.

Comment: Your answer is really awesome, also can we determine the convergence of this integral?if yes then how, because I really don't know how to do that

Comment: @user715522 I've added the proof of convergence as *Zacky* suggested in the comments.

Comment: Also, there is a chance for the following shortcut in the computation: Indeed for $x,y>0$ we have by using the subsitution $u=\frac{t}{1-t}$: $$\int_0^\infty u^{x-1} (1+u)^{-(x+y)}\,\mathrm du = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{x-1} \cdot (1-t)^{-(x+y)} \cdot (1-t)^{-2} \, \mathrm dt = \operatorname B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$ (in your particular case, $x=y=\frac13$).

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I always forget about this particular integral representation of the Beta Function... Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: @mrtaurho I didn't know about it before writing the above comment but when I saw $\frac{\Gamma(1/3)^2}{\Gamma(2/3)}$ I was like "there must be a Beta function somewhere" 

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \root{x^{4} + x}}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{\infty}^{0}{-\,\dd x/x^{2} \over \root{1/x^{4} + 1/x}}
\\[5mm] = &
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \root{x^{3} + 1}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\large x\ =\ \pars{1/t - 1}^{1/3}}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}t^{-5/6}\pars{1 - t}^{-2/3}\,\dd t =
{1 \over 3}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/6}\Gamma\pars{1/3} \over \Gamma\pars{1/2}}
\\[6mm] = &\
{1 \over 3}\,{\bracks{\vphantom{\Large A}
\pars{1/6}\Gamma\pars{1/6}}\Gamma\pars{1/3} \over  \root{\pi}}\, 6
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\large{2\,\Gamma\pars{1/3}\Gamma\pars{7/6} \over \root{\pi}}}\ \approx 2.8044 \\ &
\end{align}